# Interrupt SignalR while loop

Tags: c#, signalr

I am experimenting with developing an Asp.Net web application to allow me to tail log files. I am trying out SignalR. I have it working fine, the only problem is I can't get it to stop. I have a Log view that has a div and two buttons. Start and Stop. The Start button starts a tail, and the Stop button should stop it but it doesn't.

My TailHub.cs class reads as follows

```
using ADLK.AppManager.Domain.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace ADLK.AppManager.Web.Hubs
{
    public class TailHub : Hub
    {
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource; 
        private readonly IFileService _fileService;
        private bool _connected;
        public TailHub(IFileService fileService)
        {
            _fileService = fileService;
        }

        private async Task _fileService_FileUpdated(object sender, Domain.EventArgs.TailUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            await SendMessage(e.Text);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            if (_connected) return;
            tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _connected = true;
            _fileService.FileUpdated -= _fileService_FileUpdated;
            _fileService.FileUpdated += _fileService_FileUpdated;
            _fileService.StartMonitoringAsync(@"c:\temp\testlog.log", tokenSource.Token);
        }


        public void Stop()
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            _fileService.StopMonitoring();
            tokenSource.Dispose();
        }


        public async Task SendMessage(string message)
        {
            if (Clients != null)
            {
                await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My tail.js reads as follows

```
"use strict";

let textDiv;
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/tailhub").build();

$(document).ready(function () {
    textDiv = document.getElementById("textdiv");
    textDiv.scrollTop = textDiv.scrollHeight;

    $("#startButton").on("click", function () {
        connection.send("Start");
    });

    $("#stopButton").on("click", function () {
        connection.send("Stop");
    });

    connection.start().then(fulfilled, rejected);
});

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (value) => {
    textDiv.innerText += value.toString() + "\r\n";
});

function fulfilled() {

    console.log("Connection to Test Hub Successful.");
}


function rejected() {
    console.log("Error Connectingn to Test Hub.");
}
```

My FileService reads as follows

```
 public class FileService : IFileService
    {
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(); 
        public event AsyncEventHandler<TailUpdatedEventArgs> FileUpdated;


        public void StopMonitoring()
        {
            _tokenSource.Cancel();
        }


        public async Task StartMonitoringAsync(string tailFilePath, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            await Tail(tailFilePath, ct);
        }


        private async Task Tail(string filePath, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            using var reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite));
            //start at the end of the file
            var lastMaxOffset = reader.BaseStream.Length;

            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100, ct);

                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }

                //if the file size has not changed, idle
                if (reader.BaseStream.Length == lastMaxOffset)
                    continue;

                //seek to the last max offset
                reader.BaseStream.Seek(lastMaxOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                //read out of the file until the EOF
                while (await reader.ReadLineAsync() is { } line)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(line);
                    OnFileUpdated(new TailUpdatedEventArgs { Text = line });
                }

                //update the last max offset
                lastMaxOffset = reader.BaseStream.Position;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnFileUpdated(TailUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            FileUpdated?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
```

My Tail View is shown below.
The problem I am having is that the Tail method, runs in an infinate loop. I have tried it with a Cancellation Token and a bool (while running).  Once I start it, When I click the stop button, it never hits my hub. The stop button does work. If I click it before clicking start, it hits the hub.  Also I am aware that clicking the Stop button, actually creates a new Hub instance so my CancellationToken is null anyway.

Can anyone suggest a better way to approach this?  I want to be able to start tailing a log file, and stop from the UI.  Very grateful for any inpout.

[image]

Comment: Using hub context inside the file service would be better. A hub instance will be created for each request.

Comment: Hi Eldar, Do you mean inject something like IHubContext<TailHub> _hubContext into FileService? How would that work? How would it map to javascript - tail.js? How would js talk to it?

Comment: Your hub will be the same send message and same configuration without the fileservice and the js side will remain the same

Comment: Eldar, Many thanks for the input. As it happens, I have a version of this working now. I did indeed inject the hubcontext as you suggest, that gives me the life cycle I need. I also had to change the way I was reading the log file. I went from an infinite loop (the real issue) to a timer.  This allows me to interrupt the operation and stop it etc.